# I can’t tame my ocelot

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I fed multiple ocelots *raw* salmon until they had the hearts coming off of them but they wouldn’t tame. They didn’t run away but they didn’t become tame cats and they wouldn’t follow me. Essentially the previously wild ocelot became like any passive mob such as a pig: you can lure it but it’ll never become domesticated. I guess basically it was only in “breeding mode” but it clearly “loved” me, however, for some reason, it didn’t want to follow me.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer tame ocelots in 1.14, if that's what your using. You can now find cats in villages which can be tamed. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat

See top of https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot